# c++ registry read/write from a non-admin Windows Service

Tags: c++, service, registry

I'd like to read/write some registry information from my non-admin Windows Service, and have it applied regardless of the user logged in.  Would using a subkey of HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT do the trick?

Essentially, something like CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA but in the registry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "have it applied"?  I assume you mean write it to one place and all other users can read it; in that case, HLKM is the only answer.  Why not change your service to run under one of the service accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a key under HKLM and set the ACL to allow all users read/write access. Obviously you would need to do it from an account with sufficient privileges to begin with.